# How to fetch Gerrit Change Patch Sets in Eclipse with Mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, git, fetch, gerrit, mylyn

**Set Up**

- Gerrit: 2.8.5
- Eclipse: Luna
- Mylyn: 3.12 (Gerrit connector included)

**Question**

I'm searching for a way to fetch changes (patch sets) from Gerrit easier in Eclipse. EGit already provides a way with "Fetch from Gerrit" but a drawback here is that you always have to remember the internal change/patch ID.

With Mylyn I have a good overview of all review entries and in addition there is a button "**Fetch**" for every single patch set (besides "Publish Comments", "Compare With Base", "Rebase", "Submit", "Abandon" and "Restore"). But unfortunatly this one is not working for me.

I always get the message:

"*The referenced Git repository was not found in the workspace. Clone Git repository?*"

By clicking on "OK" nothing happens at all.

Do I have to change some settings to make this working for me?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into something that looked exactly what you see.

In my case I had to change the Hostname in the task repository ( Task Repository View -> Reviews -> mygerritserver -> Properties )

Apparently there is a Problem when the Mylyn Review URL and Git Repo URL differ too much.